# Excel: Select all that are not in a set of values (and delete)

Tags: microsoft-excel, selection, cells

I have a list of zip codes, but only a handful of them are needed.

In Excel, how do you select all rows which do not meet (or inversely meet) a set of criteria?

Comment: It isn't. and you can try use [filter](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-data-in-a-range-or-table-HP010073941.aspx?fromAR=1)

Comment: I discovered that pretty early. No biggie...thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using Excel's AutoFilter functionality, which will filter in or out records in a data range. To set it up, select a cell within the data range (preferably with column headers), and select Filter.

On the Data tab of the ribbon you have two choices.

- The Filter button will put a dropdown at the top of each column. You can use that to put up to two conditions on each column. When there's a need for a more complex set of criteria, I sometimes put a helper column in the data range, with a boolean formula that will evaluate to a single True/False (or 1/0) that can be set as the filter condition This might be, for example, `=AND(B2=$A$1,C2<>="NY"` or a little trickier formula that returns True if the target column does not equal values in a range, `=ISERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,$C2$C7,0))`. The result of the filter can be copied and then pasted to another location.
- Another option is to set an advanced filter, which is accessed by selecting the Advanced button next to the Filter button on the Data tab of the ribbon. The result of the filter will at your option be copied by Excel either in-place or in another location. You set the criteria for the filter in a criteria range in the worksheet (examples of conditions in the criteria range can be found by searching on "advanced filter" using Excel's built-in help).